# Nestjs displays error during production that: "Persisted queries are enabled and are using an unbounded cache."

Tags: caching, graphql, nestjs, apollo

Nestjs application does not display the error message during development only during production. I found no module where the apollo -server can be configured to `cache: "bounded"`. The Nestjs documentation itself makes no mention of it anywhere.
The complete error message says:

Persisted queries are enabled and are using an unbounded cache. Your server is vulnerable to denial of service attacks via memory exhaustion. Set `cache: "bounded"` or `persistedQueries: false` in your ApolloServer constructor, or see https://go.apollo.dev/s/cache-backends for other alternatives.
Here are some dependencies I suspect could be related to it.

```
"@nestjs/apollo": "10.0.19",
"@nestjs/common": "9.0.5",
"@nestjs/core": "9.0.5",
"@nestjs/graphql": "10.0.20",
```

A similar issue was opened at [github](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/13646) and sadly it was closed without any solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the Apollo module's configuration, by default the cache is "unbounded" and not safe for production (see : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/cache-backends/#ensuring-a-bounded-cache)

You can easily follow their recommendation by adding the optional "cache" configuration inside your GraphQL module.

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  cache: 'bounded', // <--- This option
  ...
}
```

Or provide an external caching with **KeyvAdapter** see:  https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-utils/tree/main/packages/keyvAdapter#keyvadapter-class

Comment: your response is helpful however I am using 

  ```
 GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      useClass: GqlConfigService,
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

In the app.module.ts inside the import array,

```
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      useClass: GqlConfigService,
    }),
```

Then in the `GqlConfigService` I add `cache: 'bounded'` in the `ApolloDriverConfig` options.

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { GraphqlConfig } from './config.interface';

@Injectable()
export class GqlConfigService implements GqlOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
  createGqlOptions(): ApolloDriverConfig {
    const graphqlConfig = this.configService.get<GraphqlConfig>('graphql');
    return {
      // schema options
      cache: 'bounded', // ! <== Added here
      autoSchemaFile: graphqlConfig.schemaDestination || './src/schema.graphql',
      sortSchema: graphqlConfig.sortSchema,
      buildSchemaOptions: {
        numberScalarMode: 'integer',
      },
      // subscription
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      debug: graphqlConfig.debug,
      playground: graphqlConfig.playgroundEnabled,
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    };
  }
}
```